# Delete lines above and below a string from json file

Tags: json, sed

I have a my_file.json file, which contains invalid json as below, and i need to delete the lines starting from "{" upto "}," if the "name": my_script.py.

```
[
            {
                "use":                     abcd   
                "name":                    my_script.py
                "contact":                 xyz
                "time":                    11:22:33
             },
            {
                "use":                     abcd   
                "name":                    some_other_script.py
                "contact":                 xyz
                "time":                    11:22:33
             },
            {
                "use":                     abcd   
                "name":                    my_script.py
                "contact":                 xyz
                "time":                    11:22:33
             }
]
```

I tried below sed,

```
sed '//{/ {:a;/}/!{N;ba};/my_script/d}' my_file.json
```

but it is not working and giving me error

```
"sed: -e expression#1, char 11: `}' doesn't want any addresses".
```

Comment: if it is possible to install another tool, use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead of `sed` to process json

Comment: unfortunately, No

Comment: Then use Python. Python has json support per default. But don't use sed.

Comment: The example given is not json. If I run `jq . file` where `file` contains the example it does not parse `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 3, column 48`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/my_script\.py/d}' file
```

Gather up the lines between `{` and `}` and if those lines contain `my_script.py` delete them.

The current example is not json, however this is probably a more robust solution:

```
sed 's/\S\+/"&"/2;T;N;/}/!s/\n/,&/;P;D' file |
jq '[ .[]|select(.name!="my_script.py") ]'
```